# RegExp: Match string between ampersands

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regExp to read URL parameters. I need to perform a Match on the following string :

```
SomeMoreText&action='{%22JsonParameter%22:[%221234%22]}'&SomeMoreText
```

The end result should be

```
                         '{%22JsonParameter%22:[%221234%22]}'
```

I'm gessing I need an expression to find everything between &action= and the following &. I tried different expressions with no success and, to be honest, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding regular expression syntax. The problem here is the colon, quotes (%22) and brackets I think. If it was only text, I believe something like this would work :

```
/action=([\w\-]+)/
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm no Regex Pro myself (hence why I'm leaving this as a comment) but could you not keep it simple and do `.+=('.+').+` ?. EG: http://rubular.com/r/CIeIuizhMn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How 'bout

```
var m = /action=([^&]+)/.exec(str);
if (m) {
    // The content is in m[1]
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ijotod/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ijotod/1/edit)

Comment: This answer and the following one, By Bruno, are my favorite solutions. I wish I could mark them both as correct. However, this one answers the the question by strictly using regexp so I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Just upvote them both, but it's understood how you have to select one of them;-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex, just try this:

```
var n=str.split("&");
```

Comment: Yep, that's my fallback solution. However, I'm using Dojo (which I'll add as a tag) and it's kind of complicated to implement in the dojoconfig file.

Comment: This does not actually output the end result specified in the question.

Comment: like this, split has to be faster than regExp, but need to check.
how about bit perfomance `spl = str.split('&')[1].split('=')[1];`

Comment: I know it doesn'T produce then final result but you just have to keep using string operations to find the value... pretty straightforward after the ampersand split

Comment: @Ggilmann yea regex is winner, good boy, my new favorite) http://jsperf.com/split-vs-regexpr-who-is-faster

Comment: guys you see that, how much Chrome is good with regExpr, and how FF bad in there, could not believe it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positive and negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They are `(?<= expression )` and `(?= expression )` respectfully.

The following will do non-greedy look for any character, `.*?`, that is preceded by 'action=', `(?<=action=)`, and is followed by '&', `(?=&)`.

The full regex is: `(?<=action=).*?(?=&)`

You can test this [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
result = str.split("action=")[1];
result = result.substring( 0, result.indexOf("&") );
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/tqRgX/)

Answer (score 0):

As @PearsonArtPhoto previously said you can simply use split :

```
var results=str.split("&");
```

And then iterate though results array like below:

```
for(i=0; i< results.length ; i++){
  if( results[i].split('=')[0] == 'action'){  // this condition to test that the key is 'action'
  return results[i].split('=')[1];
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.